# Pessimistic locking is not running as expected when running from another thread

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 3 with SQL server which seems to have isolation level as read committed. I'm expecting to see here an exception in main thread but I'm not getting any.

Not sure what seems wrong. Could you suggest?

Test controller

```
        callTest();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void callTest() throws InterruptedException {
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        //set
        cart = cartRepository.save(cart);

        // Create a CountDownLatch with a count of 1
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Cart finalCart = cart;
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                logger.info("Updated from spwan thread");
                updateCArt(finalCart.getCartID() , "New Name");
                latch.countDown(); // Decrement the count when the thread finishes
                Thread.sleep(1900L);
            } catch (PessimisticLockException e) {
                // Ignore
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        t.start();

        // Wait for the latch to reach zero
        latch.await();

       
        try {
            logger.info("Updated from main thread");
            updateCArt(cart.getCartID(), "Another New Name");
        } catch (PessimisticLockException e) {
            logger.info("Exception in main thread ", e);
            // Expected
        }
        logger.info("Completed succesfully");
    }

    public Cart updateCArt(int id, String newName) {
        logger.info("Enetering updateCart method ");
        List<Cart> cart = cartRepository.getCarts("678999", 2L);
        cart.get(0).setStatus(1);
        return cartRepository.save(cart.get(0));
    }
```

Query

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Cart c ")
    List<Cart> getCarts(snip);
```

Comment: I don't see how you can spin up a new thread within a transactional context - you need separate multiple threads that call a transactional method concurrently. You also have the save itself marked as transactional - which will end when the method call returns, releasing your lock - but since it is a local call, it might not get a transaction started for it at all.

Comment: @Chris Thanks it makes sense. I changed my code to have the controller public method be transactional and hit two requests that gets different records one after other. The latest one also blocks otherwise it runs(thread sleep is run on the first record). Why might this happen? Can I skip adding Transactional on service method as my service method does a lot of heavy lifting like 3rd party api calls?